# Scan and render junit tests from external files

Tags: java, junit, runtime

There are 2 files **outside** of the application (`A.class` and `ATest.class`).

How can we scan `ATest` to find all junit tests and run them (assuming the dependencies of `ATest` are loaded in classpath except `A`)? I'm looking for doing this programmatically in Java and as a result having the list of the tests of `ATest`, which failed and which succeeded.

The command line must not be used (in case of we need a more complex output).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `@Test` from `org.junit.Test` to scan all methods in a `.class`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm ok to use reflection `@Test` to scan `ATest`. Now how can I run `ATest` with `JUnitCore`assuming `A` is not loaded in the classpath? I cannot use `URLClassLoader` because `ATest` doesn't. In fact I'm looking for do the same job as my IDE when I run some tests, within my application.